# Redux state is not receiving data properly from backend (mySQL)

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, redux

I have a problem rendering my data from the backend (mySQL) to the frontend. I have been debugging both in the redux devtools and console log but I still couldn't find why. The data is fetching properly in  the console log but when I log my state, it is just empty. In the redux devtools, I can see the data in the action tab and the status changes from pending to fulfilled. However when it is fulfilled, the state is just empty.

This is my initial state from my slice component:

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  error: "",
  supplierInfo: [
    {
      id: "",
      supplierName: "",
      supplierTin: "",
      supplierAddress: "",
      telNumber: "",
      celNumber: "",
      emailAddress: "",
    },
  ],
};
```

This is my fetch function (the data is being logged properly):

```
export const fetchSuppliers = createAsyncThunk(
  "/supplier/fetchSuppliers",
  async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/get");

      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
);
```

This is my slice code:

```
export const SupplierSlice = createSlice({
  name: "supplier",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addSupplier: (state, action) => {
      state.supplierInfo.push(action.payload);
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
      builder.addCase(fetchSuppliers.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      });
      builder.addCase(fetchSuppliers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.supplierInfo = action.payload;
        state.error = "";
      });
      builder.addCase(fetchSuppliers.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.supplierInfo = [];
        state.error = action.error.message;
      });
    },
  },
});
export default SupplierSlice.reducer;
export const { addSupplier } = SupplierSlice.actions;
```

My code to dispatch data:

```
export const SuppliersTable = () => {
  const suppliers = useSelector((state) => state.supplier.supplierInfo);
  console.log(suppliers);
  const data = suppliers;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchSuppliers());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

The console.log above is just empty. And I don't know why. Maybe the problem is in the reducers?I can see the data in the action tab though but it is not displaying into the state..

This is from the action tab in redux devtools:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InGb0.png)

This is from the state tab:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvJAB.png)

As you can see, nothing is being displayed into the state. And I don't know whyyyy. Can someone please help? Thank youuuu!

I have tried debugging for hours. Using log statements, redux devtools. I'm seeing data from the backend but it's not in the state.

Comment: could you pls share codesandbox of your source code?

Comment: You've a typo error in your state slice code, `extraReducers` is a root property but you've incorrectly nested it in the `reducers` object. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

###### Redux state is not receiving data bc of your code of slice format is wrong.

pls compare my example code with your real code. pls check your supplier slice code is look wrong. extraReducer should not be inside of reducer's block. if you move it out of reducer, it will work.

```
const supplierSlice = createSlice({
  name: "supplier",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchSuppliers.pending, (state, action) => {
      console.log(action);
      state.loading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchSuppliers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.supplierInfo = action.payload;
      state.loading = false;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchSuppliers.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
    });
  }
});
```

here is the example [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-shape-64xxfs?file=/src/features/supplier/supplierSlice.js)